# Displaying auto complete results a bit faster

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete

It's been quite some time since I had last visited a specific feature that we had built into an internal tool.  Basically it's a simple `input` text box field where we allow people to perform searches.  As people search we bring up an autocomplete with 5 items listed matching to what the user has searched for.

For quite some time in the beginning of this project I believe our autocomplete worked real fast - as soon as we hit three characters in this field we used to get the autocomplete to come up right away - we are using elasticsearch to index our records.  Nowadays the autocomplete works but takes way too long to get us some results.  Many times a user can enter an entire search string and when he / she hits enter to go to our search results page before it hits this page the autocomplete will finally come up.  Well that is too late for it to be coming up as the user is already headed to the results page of the search.

I thought I'd post what we are doing to see if we are missing something or if its hardware related (as we are using a VM for our searching).  In any event here we have a basic input textbox:

`<input runat="server" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="search" maxlength="100" />`

On the entry of this search box we call a function which does a search as such:

```
function DoAJAXSearch() {
    var search = $("#search").val().trim();
    var resultsToReturn = 5;
    var module;
    //have they selected a specific module to search on?
    if (search.length > 0) {
        if ($('#ddlEntity').val() === "") {
            module = 0;
        } else {
            module = $('#<%= ddlEntity.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
        }
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Code/WebServices/Search.asmx/DoSearch",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: '{"searchQuery":"' + search + '","module":"' + module + '","resultsToReturn":"' + resultsToReturn + '"}',
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                entity: item.EntityType,
                                value: item.Summary,
                                url: item.EntityLink,
                                picture: item.PicturePath == null ? "/Images/noimagefound.png" : item.PicturePath
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //log the search back to the database
                LogSearch(module, search, true);
                //end log search back to database

                //open the selected item
                window.open(ui.item.url, "_self");
            },
            open: function () {
            },
            close: function () {
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                alert(textStatus);
            },
            search: function () {
                $(this).addClass('autocompleteloading');
            },
            response: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('autocompleteloading');
            }
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            ul.addClass("addShadow");
            var face;
            if (item != null) {
                if (item.value.length > 50) {
                    face = item.value.substr(0, 50) + '...';
                } else {
                    face = item.value;
                }
                return $("<li>")
                    .append("<a title='" + item.value + "' href='" + item.url + "'><div style='float:left;width:100%;'><div class='dPicture'><img width='48px' height='48px' src='" + item.picture + "' /></div><div class='dPicture'><div class='dPictureFields'><b>" + item.entity + "</b></div><div class='dPictureFields'>" + face + "</div></div></div><div class='clear-fix'></div></a></li>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
}
```

Basically as you see here we allow the user to search across all modules or a specific module if they selected one.  We only call this web method: "DoSearch" upon entry of 3 characters.

DoSearch is a method inside of an asmx file (as this is a web form project).  It's pretty lengthy and I know very ugly but the point of it is is to capture what the user has entered and build up our elasticsearch results.  As much as I hate it its currently what we have:

```
    public List<ElasticSearchResult> DoSearch(string searchQuery, int module, int resultsToReturn = 0)
            {
                //get tag
                //user can add a tag to the search, "SearchQuery [C++]" looking for anything with SearchQuery that is tagged C++
                string tag = string.Empty;
                int pos = searchQuery.IndexOf('[', 0);
                if (pos > -1)
                {
                    int pos2 = searchQuery.IndexOf(']', pos);

                    if (pos2 > -1)
                    {
                        //we've got [ ]
                        tag = searchQuery.Substring(pos + 1, pos2 - pos - 1).ToLower();
                    }

                    if (pos > 0)
                        searchQuery = searchQuery.Substring(0, pos - 1);
                }
                //The search engine only sees /t, not a tab, so replace it with a space
                searchQuery = searchQuery.Replace("\t", " ");

                //Reserved characters:     + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
                //Remove reserved characters the user won't use
                var reserverCharacters = new List<string>
                {
                    "+",
                    "&&",
                    "||",
                    "(",
                    ")",
                    "{",
                    "}",
                    "[",
                    "]",
                    "^",
                    "~",
                    ":",
                    "\\",
                    "/"
                };
                searchQuery = reserverCharacters.Aggregate(searchQuery,
                    (current, character) => current.Replace(character, ""));

                //To prevent search errors, trim * and whitespace
                searchQuery = searchQuery.Trim(' ', '*'); 
                //Define the descriptors so they can be reused throughout this function

                var companySearchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchCompany>();

                companySearchDescriptor
                    .Size(35)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .QueryString(query => query
                            .AnalyzeWildcard()
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                                .Add(f => f.Summary, 1.6)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 1.5)
                                .Add(f => f.Description, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.City.Suffix("ngram"), 1.1)
                                .Add(f => f.City, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Tags, 1.0))
                            .Query(searchQuery)));

                var contactSearchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchContact>();
                contactSearchDescriptor
                    .Size(35)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .QueryString(query => query
                            .AnalyzeWildcard()
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                                .Add(f => f.Summary, 1.6)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 1.5)
                                .Add(f => f.Description, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Email, 1.1)
                                .Add(f => f.Email.Suffix("ngram"), 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Title, 1.1)
                                .Add(f => f.Title.Suffix("ngram"), 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Tags, 1.0))
                            .Query(searchQuery)));
                var userSearchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchUser>();
                userSearchDescriptor
                    .Size(35)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .QueryString(query => query
                            .AnalyzeWildcard()
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                                .Add(f => f.Summary, 1.6)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 1.5)
                                .Add(f => f.Description, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Email, 1.1)
                                .Add(f => f.Email.Suffix("ngram"), 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Title, 1.1)
                                .Add(f => f.Title.Suffix("ngram"), 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Tags, 1.0))
                            .Query(searchQuery)));

                var corporationSearchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchCorporation>();
                corporationSearchDescriptor
                    .Size(35)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .QueryString(query => query
                            .AnalyzeWildcard()
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                                .Add(f => f.Summary, 1.6)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 1.5)
                                .Add(f => f.Description, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Tags, 1.0))
                            .Query(searchQuery)));

                var documentSearchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchDocument>();
                documentSearchDescriptor
                    .Size(35)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .QueryString(query => query
                            .AnalyzeWildcard()
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                                .Add(f => f.Summary, 2.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 1.5)
                                .Add(f => f.Title, 1.4)
                                .Add(f => f.Title.Suffix("ngram"), 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Description, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Tags, 1.0))
                            .Query(searchQuery)));

                var checklistSearchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchChecklist>();
                checklistSearchDescriptor
                    .Size(35)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .QueryString(query => query
                            .AnalyzeWildcard()
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                                .Add(f => f.Summary, 2.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 1.9)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram_no_punct"), 1.9)
                                .Add(f => f.Id, 2.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Milestone, 1.6)
                                .Add(f => f.RecordName, 1.5)
                                .Add(f => f.RecordName.Suffix("ngram"), 1.4)
                                .Add(f => f.RecordName.Suffix("ngram_no_punct"), 1.4)
                                .Add(f => f.ParentName, 1.3)
                                .Add(f => f.ParentName.Suffix("ngram"), 1.2)
                                .Add(f => f.ParentName.Suffix("ngram_no_punct"), 1.2)
                                .Add(f => f.Description, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Tags, 1.0))
                            .Query(searchQuery)));

                var issueSearchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchIssue>();
                issueSearchDescriptor
                    .Size(35)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .QueryString(query => query
                            .AnalyzeWildcard()
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                                .Add(f => f.Summary, 1.3)
                                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 1.2)
                                .Add(f => f.Description, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.IssueNumber, 2.0)
                                .Add(f => f.LessonLearned, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Resolution, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Type, 1.0)
                                .Add(f => f.Tags, 1.0))
                            .Query(searchQuery)));

//SIMILIAR CODE FOR ALL OTHER MODULES BASED ON ISSUE ABOVE 
//TOO MUCH CODE TO POST

                //Need the client before you can make a call to the search servers
                var esClient = Code.Utilities.GetElasticClient();
                if (esClient == null) return null; 
                IMultiSearchResponse result;

                //Each case(other than default) handles if the user chose to only search for a single type of module
                switch (module)
                {
                    case (int) Module.Company:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchCompany>(a => companySearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Contact:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchContact>(a => contactSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Corporate:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchCorporation>(a => corporationSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Checklist:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchChecklist>(a => checklistSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Document:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchDocument>(a => documentSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Issue:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchIssue>(a => issueSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.TaskReminder:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchTaskReminder>(a => taskSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.LessonLearned:
                    {
                        result =
                            esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                                .Search<ElasticSearchLessonLearned>(a => lessonLearnedSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Program:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchProgram>(a => programSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Project:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchProject>(a => projectSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.SubProject:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchSubProject>(a => subprojectSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.ServiceOrder:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchServiceOrder>(a => serviceOrderDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Meeting:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchMeeting>(a => meetingSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Tip:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchTip>(a => tipSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Incident:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchIncident>(a => incidentSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Material:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchMaterial>(a => materialSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.Training:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchTraining>(a => trainingSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) Module.User:
                    {
                        result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                            .Search<ElasticSearchUser>(a => userSearchDescriptor));
                        break;
                    }
                    default: //Handles the "All" type search
                    {
                        //LessonLearned results are Issues, don't want to search them twice in "All" type search
                        if (MySession.Current.User.IsAdmin)
                        {
                            //allow user search
                            result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                                .Search<ElasticSearchCompany>(a => companySearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchContact>(a => contactSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchUser>(a => userSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchCorporation>(a => corporationSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchChecklist>(a => checklistSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchDocument>(a => documentSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchIssue>(a => issueSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchTaskReminder>(a => taskSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchProgram>(a => programSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchProject>(a => projectSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchSubProject>(a => subprojectSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchServiceOrder>(a => serviceOrderDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchMeeting>(a => meetingSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchTraining>(a => trainingSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchIncident>(a => incidentSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchMaterial>(a => materialSearchDescriptor)
                                .Search<ElasticSearchTip>(a => tipSearchDescriptor));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = esClient.MultiSearch(search => search
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchCompany>(a => companySearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchContact>(a => contactSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchCorporation>(a => corporationSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchChecklist>(a => checklistSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchDocument>(a => documentSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchIssue>(a => issueSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchTaskReminder>(a => taskSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchProgram>(a => programSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchProject>(a => projectSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchSubProject>(a => subprojectSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchServiceOrder>(a => serviceOrderDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchMeeting>(a => meetingSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchTraining>(a => trainingSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchIncident>(a => incidentSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchMaterial>(a => materialSearchDescriptor)
                                    .Search<ElasticSearchTip>(a => tipSearchDescriptor)
                            );
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                List<ElasticSearchResult> esSearchResultList =
                    ParseSearchResults(result, MySession.Current.User.IsAdmin).ToList();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag) && tag.Length > 0)
                    esSearchResultList = esSearchResultList.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(a => a == tag)).ToList();

                //we need to reserve the order of the result 
                //so we added a new property called sort order which we will update below
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var esr in esSearchResultList)
                {
                    esr.SortOrder = counter;
                    counter++;
                }

                //Remove any results the user doesn't have permission to see
                var entityResultList = new List<ElasticSearchResult>();
                //this is a inteermediate place holder for records
                var filteredResultList = new List<ElasticSearchResult>();
                //this will have the final result after filtering 

                //get the search entity list
                var entityList = CachedData.EntitySearchList;
                using (var db = DataCenterAccess.NewConnection())
                {
                    //loop thru the entity search to filter what the current user can /cannot see
                    foreach (var entity in entityList)
                    {
                        //get user permission for current entity
                        Answer permission =
                            (Answer) MySession.Current.Permission.GetPermission(entity.EntityID, (int) ActionEnum.View);

                        if (permission == Answer.Yes)
                        {
                            //if yes get all records for that entity type
                            entityResultList = esSearchResultList.Where(x => x.EntityId == entity.EntityID).ToList();
                        }
                        else if (permission == Answer.Originator)
                        {
                            //if originator ; get only record the user can see for that entity type
                            entityResultList =
                                esSearchResultList.Where(
                                    x =>
                                        x.EntityId == entity.EntityID &&
                                        x.AddedByUserId == MySession.Current.User.UserId).ToList();
                        }

                        //add the result to the final result list
                        filteredResultList.AddRange(entityResultList);
                    }

                    //now we need to isolate the records that are private based on the team record security
                    var privateRecords = filteredResultList.Where(x => x.Private).ToList();

                    //also make sure the filtered list does not have any of the private records
                    filteredResultList = filteredResultList.Where(x => !x.Private).ToList();

                    if (privateRecords.Any())
                    {
                        //if we have any private records
                        //we need to loop thru and see if the user is on a team that has access to the record
                        foreach (var esr in privateRecords)
                        {
                            if (RIMSBL.Code.DAL.UserHasTeamPermission(db, esr.EntityId, esr.RecordId,
                                MySession.Current.User.UserId))
                                filteredResultList.Add(esr);
                        }
                    }
                }
                    //0 means return all. If not 0, then limit to that number of search results
                if (resultsToReturn != 0)
                {
                    filteredResultList = filteredResultList.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).Take(resultsToReturn).ToList();
                }
                return filteredResultList;
            }
```

I'm not sure if the issue is related to data as we are only processing something in the hundreds of thousands of records (across all modules).  One thing we do, do is as you type letters into the search textbox we continuously call DoSearch and it returns a status code when it is done.  So if you type in 7 characters do search would be called on the 3rd chacter up until the 7th character (total of 5 times) as shown in chrome console:

[image]

The only other thing I can think about is maybe we just need better hardware.  This server stats:

[image]

The search server is low on memory I know but before I request additional hardware I wanted to see if I was missing anything.

Comment: First rule of optimization is "Measure it". Have you tried to measue what exactly takes much time? Do subsequent request actually slowdown first one (i.e. measure response time for just 3 letters vs response time for 3 letters and you continue entering)? Obvious things to measure are: time of MultiSearch  under `switch (module)`, of `ParseSearchResults` of following filtering by Tag (by the way, can't you move it to the ElasticSearch?), and the time of final block with potential access to DB. Then you (and we) can see what requires further attention.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is use Chrome DevTools to determine if your bottleneck is on the backend or front end. (Serializing results or rendering them). Can we see the detail for one of those `DoSearch` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have to measure if it's the server or the client (browser). Add a breakpoint to the server code and step through it to get the idea.

Then. To prevent multiple requests to the server add a `delay` option to your autocomplete init:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    delay: 550,
    //continued...
});
```

This way autocomplete only works when the user pauses typing for 550ms or longer. Experiment with the value.

Also, I noticed you're **re-initializing autocomplete every time** in the `DoAJAXSearch` function, is this the intended behaviour? When is this function `DoAJAXSearch` being called exactly? On *every keystroke*? No wonder it's so slow then. Automcomplete should be initialized only once on page load.

Something like this:

```
$(function() { //this is a shortcut for "run this code when document is ready"
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var search = $("#search").val().trim();
            var resultsToReturn = 5;
            var module;
            if ($('#ddlEntity').val() === "") {
                module = 0;
            } else {
                module = $('#<%= ddlEntity.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Code/WebServices/Search.asmx/DoSearch",
                dataType: "json",
                data: '{"searchQuery":"' + search + '","module":"' + module + '","resultsToReturn":"' + resultsToReturn + '"}',
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            entity: item.EntityType,
                            value: item.Summary,
                            url: item.EntityLink,
                            picture: item.PicturePath == null ? "/Images/noimagefound.png" : item.PicturePath
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        delat: 550,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //log the search back to the database
            LogSearch(module, search, true);
            //end log search back to database

            //open the selected item
            window.open(ui.item.url, "_self");
        },
        open: function () {
        },
        close: function () {
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        search: function () {
            $(this).addClass('autocompleteloading');
        },
        response: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('autocompleteloading');
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        ul.addClass("addShadow");
        var face;
        if (item != null) {
            if (item.value.length > 50) {
                face = item.value.substr(0, 50) + '...';
            } else {
                face = item.value;
            }
            return $("<li>")
                .append("<a title='" + item.value + "' href='" + item.url + "'><div style='float:left;width:100%;'><div class='dPicture'><img width='48px' height='48px' src='" + item.picture + "' /></div><div class='dPicture'><div class='dPictureFields'><b>" + item.entity + "</b></div><div class='dPictureFields'>" + face + "</div></div></div><div class='clear-fix'></div></a></li>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
        return false;
    };
});
```

PS. A 16gig server is totally fine, shouldn't be a bottle neck for asp.net.

Comment: Ok i can add the delay...But regarding initilization.  My key event is claling this function DoAjaxSearch.  If I remove the initialization of autocomplete how will this method then look?  In addition, the autocomplete has a source within it.  If I do not include this inside of DoAjaxSearch what would this method look like without the autocomplete?

Comment: @JonH you don't need `DoAJAXSearch` function at all because `.autocomplete` binds its own keypress-handler to the textbox. Move your logic to the `function (request, response)` function body, like extracting data from dropdown-lists etc. before calling actual `$.ajax`. And initialize autocomplete on `document.ready`

Comment: Im not sure I follow, can you edit your answer and take my function and modify.  Assume I call this function from two different places one         `$('#search').on('input keyup paste', function () {
            DoAJAXSearch();
        });` and another change event inside of a drop down list.

Comment: But what if my dropdown value changes values or my textbox changes values how does autocomplete know this?  In addition, in my drop down change event Im currently calling this DoAjaxSearch...what would I change that too now?

Comment: This function is called **every time** you press a key, so it will have the updated data.

Comment: As well as the change in my drop down value?  How does autocomplete know this - is this some internal details?

Comment: Its doe not know this and it is not called upon dropdown change, but it will know the new value once its called next time you press a key

Comment: But there are times I am just changing my drop down value not changes keys in my text box #search.  I have two controls that should affect this autocomplete one is a simple textbox (#search) the other is a drop down list (#ddlEntity).

Comment: Anyway. You asked "why is it so slow". Like I said - *because you keep re-initting autocomplete.* That's not how its done. Asking people to refactor your code for is not stackoverflow's job.

Comment: Also, your question (which is 3 screens long by the way) never mentions that dropdownlist should trigger autocomplete as well.

Comment: understandable I didn't want to mention each detail but now when you mentioned my error I would like to resolve it with the fact that this function is called from 2 different controls.  This is why I asked.  So I guess my question is will autocomplete take in my drop down changes as well as my textbox changes?  Where in the initilization of this control are you telling it what controls affects it?

Comment: jquery-autocomplete does not support initializing from multiple controls. If you want to trigger autocomplete manually, call this: `$("#search").autocomplete("search");` (for example when your dwopdownlist changes) https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

Comment: jazzcat - ok i will try some of this today and let you know.  thanks for the great help...

Comment: Wow - I cannot believe I missed the fact that I was re initializing it.  Your code sent me in the right direction.  I had some minor issues to fix along with your proposed changes but I am already seeing a dramatic difference.  Bounty is yours pal.

Comment: @JonH not seeing it awarded though

Comment: I think it may take some time for it to be awarded. But i did accept your answer and awarded bounty. Be patient.